# In React, useMemo hook's warning of dependency array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
 const [getNum, setNum] = useState(1);
  function generateNum(){
    let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    setNum(randomNum);
 }

 const doubleNum = useMemo(()=>{ 
    return doubleTheNum();
 }, [getNum]) 

 function doubleTheNum(){
   return getNum * 2;
 }
```

My confusion is on warning that was given by compiler.

```
WARNING in [eslint] 
src\AppMemo.js
  Line 51:6:  React Hook useMemo has a missing dependency: 'doubleTheNum'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

webpack compiled with 1 warning
```

But if I pass `getNum` (which is the state variable) to `doubleTheNum` function (that I called inside `useMemo`) then it will completely successfully compiled without any warnings.

Although without this, just warning thrown but I want to know what exactly is happening and what I should consider? What should I make sure while using `useMemo` hooks in React?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is pointing you to the missing dependency `doubleTheNum` in the `memo`ized function `doubleNum`.

You should add it to the dependency array like:

```
const doubleNum = useMemo(()=>{ 
    return doubleTheNum(); // `doubleTheNum` called inside `useMemo`
 }, [doubleTheNum]) // so `doubleNum` is **dependant** on `doubleTheNum`
```

Please try and read [the official react documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo#parameters) first as it is quite well explained over there!

Edit:

You will also need to wrap the `doubleTheNum` method in a `useCallback` with its' own dependency array.

You can do this like:

```
const doubleTheNum = useCallback(() => {
   return getNum * 2; // Is using the `getNum`
}, [getNum]) // So this is **dependant** on `getNum`
```

It seems like you do not have a full clear understanding of the workings of dependency arrays of react. [this article](https://devtrium.com/posts/dependency-arrays) might help you get a better understanding. Also, as mentioned before, please do read the official react documentation as it is quite well documented how these things work.

Comment: if I do this, then it throws this warning:
`WARNING in [eslint]
src\AppMemo.js
  Line 53:3:  The 'doubleTheNum' function makes the dependencies of useMemo Hook (at line 51) change on every render. Move it inside the useMemo callback. Alternatively, wrap the definition of 'doubleTheNum' in its own useCallback() Hook  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

Comment: the errors you are getting are pointing you to exactly what you need to do, please do read the react documentation as it is very well documented on how these things work